# JavaScript - optimising download times with ES* modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to know how modules are included when using ES2015 modules, and how to optimize modules for the best download experience. This question compares two strategies for code organisation.

*With respect to the first comment left on this question, this refers to comparison of the two scenarios with native ES modules, but answers relating to bundling/minification tools are also welcome.*

### Scenario 1 - Single File

*foobar.js*

```
export class Foo {
    constructor(message) {
        alert(message);
    }
}

export class Bar {
    constructor(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}
```

*program.js*

```
import { Foo } from "foobar.js";

class Program {
    constructor() {
        this.greeter = new Foo("hello world");
    }
}
```

### Scenario 2 - Multiple Files

*foo.js*

```
export class Foo {
    constructor(message) {
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

*bar.js*

```
export class Bar {
    constructor(message) {
        console.log(message);
    }
}
```

*program.js*

```
import { Foo } from "foo.js";

class Program {
    constructor() {
        this.greeter = new Foo("hello world");
    }
}
```

In scenario 1, both `Foo` and `Bar` are declared in *foobar.js*, whereas in scenario 2, they are in separate files. *program.js* imports only `Foo` in either scenario. What I want to know is, when there are multiple exports in a single file, does the whole file need to be served in order to fulfill the import statement, and if this is the case, is it better to keep each declaration in it's own file in order to reduce the download size?

*For extra kudos, what are the best practices for dealing with imports over the web, and what tools exist to help simplify this process?*

Comment: It's unclear if you refer to native ES modules or their implementations in bundling tools.

Comment: @estus I've added another statement at the top of the post to clarify this.

Comment: This depends on what 'download experience' refers to. For high speed it's generally bundling (you have full control over separate chunks in Webpack). For low traffic usage it's native with a heap of files (not counting the fact that native modules don't have much support) - there's no way how a file can be partially downloaded to provide one export and discard another one.

Comment: @estus download experience refers to high speed. Say for example I have a js file that contains 1MB of javascript, contained in 100 exported classes, and I only want to use one of them in a particular scenario. Does the entire 1MB (bundling/minification aside) have to be downloaded, or is the class I'm importing somehow request only the required code?

Comment: If the code isn't used anywhere else, it can be discarded with tree shaking in Rollup or Webpack. If some code is used in specific places, bundled file can be chunked into several pieces. 1MB is much smaller when being minified and gzipped. IRL one big JS file usually beats a flock of small files (there may be exceptions with HTTP/2 server AND browser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually depends on the bundler. If your bundler supports Tree Shaking (like [Webpack 2+](https://webpack.js.org/) and [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) does) then both will give the same output.

#### Scenario 1:

See [this example](https://rollupjs.org/repl?version=0.50.0&shareable=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). You will find that `Bar` is already stripped in the final bundle because of tree shaking. But you have to keep in mind that it only works for ES6 modules and not for CommonJS modules. So make sure that you are importing the ES6 build for this feature. There are slight differences in how Webpack and Rollup handle this.

**Webpack** : It actually makes `Bar` dead code by removing module.exports from the resulting bundle. When you run uglify on it, that part of code is removed. So here you need uglifier to remove the unused code.

**Rollup**: The dead code is removed right after you pass it through Rollup. This is the reason why many popular libraries have moved to Rollup for bundling.

#### Scenario 2:

You already get an optimized output.

So in both cases, you can get the same optimized result provided your tooling and setup is right.